# App keeps crashing when I switch to landscape mode

Tags: java, android-studio

I have been working on a basic `Calculator` App in Android Studios. I've gotten preety deep into it and I am happy with my progress so far. The problem that I am now facing is that when I am running the `Calculator` App, whenever I input a number in portrait mode and switch into landscape mode and try to add a number or do any operation on it, the app crashes. I used the `onSaveInstanceState` method to save the data and the `onRestoreInstanceState` method to retrieve it. I looked into documentation on how to use these two methods and I am sure that I am implemented them correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

I have pasted the code down below.

```
package com.mohamedali.calculatorapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText moeresult;
private EditText moenewNumber;
private TextView displayOperation;

//Comment: Variables to hold the operands and type of calculations

private Double operand1 = null;
private String pendingOperation = " = ";

public static final String STATE_PENDING_OPERATION = "Pending Operation";
public static final String STATE_OPERAND1 = "Operand 1";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    moeresult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
    moenewNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewNumber);
    displayOperation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Operation);

    Button button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button buttonDecimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDecimal);
    Button buttonMultiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
    Button buttonDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
    Button buttonMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
    Button buttonPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
    Button buttonEqual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEqual);


    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v;
            moenewNumber.append(b.getText().toString());
        }
    };


    button0.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button3.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button4.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button5.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button6.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button7.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button8.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button9.setOnClickListener(listener);
    buttonDecimal.setOnClickListener(listener);


    View.OnClickListener opListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button b = (Button) view;
            String op = b.getText().toString();
            String value = moenewNumber.getText().toString();
            try {
                Double doublevalue = Double.valueOf(value);
                performOperation(doublevalue, op);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                moenewNumber.setText("");
            }
            pendingOperation = op;
            displayOperation.setText(pendingOperation);

        }

    };

    buttonEqual.setOnClickListener(opListener);
    buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(opListener);
    buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(opListener);
    buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(opListener);
    buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(opListener);


}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(STATE_PENDING_OPERATION, pendingOperation);
    if (operand1 != null) {
        outState.putDouble(STATE_PENDING_OPERATION, operand1);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    pendingOperation = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_PENDING_OPERATION);
    operand1 = savedInstanceState.getDouble(STATE_OPERAND1);
    displayOperation.setText(pendingOperation);
}

private void performOperation(Double value, String operation) {

    // first thing is that it checks if first value is null
    if (null == operand1) {
        operand1 = value;
    } else {
        if (pendingOperation.equals(" = ")) {
            pendingOperation = operation;
        }
        switch (pendingOperation) {
            case "=":
                operand1 = value;
                break;
            case "/":
                if (value == 0) {
                    operand1 = 0.0;
                } else {
                    operand1 /= value;
                }
                break;
            case "*":
                operand1 *= value;
                break;
            case "-":
                operand1 -= value;
                break;
            case "+":
                operand1 += value;
                break;
        }
    }
    // Displays the result
    moeresult.setText(operand1.toString());
    // It then clears it
    moenewNumber.setText("");
  }


}
```

Comment: Look at the call stack from the crash - it will literally tell you what you are crashing on.

Comment: I have looked at it and its saying it has trouble with this line of code:      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                                               What does this mean?

Comment: Publish your entire crash stack.

Comment: i got it to work thanks @selbie